# While using session based model , getting error "undefined local variable or method session for " in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

code which giving error is in `CommentsController`

```
if @comments.save
    user_session.add_comment(@comments)  // this is cause of error
    # session[:comment_ids] ||= []
    # session[:comment_ids] << @comments.id
    flash[:notice] = "Comment Successfully created"
    redirect_to @post
else
    redirect_to :back
end
```

When I go to edit comment which is stored in session for 1 minute. I got this error:

```
NameError in CommentsController#create
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<UserSession:0xaca0684>
```

`add_comment` is defined in session model.

One more thing I want to say that error occurs because I used a centralized location through session model otherwise commented code above was working fine.

Comment: Can you please post the code, specific question, and error here?  Users are not going to want to dig through your repo and try to find what is wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: what is `user_session`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've refactored the commented out code into the `user_session` object.

If you read the error message you see that the error references a variable `session for #<UserSession:0xXXXXX>`. From this I understand that you tried to reference the `session` object from within the `UserSession` class, but you *did not pass it* to the `user_session` object.

You should add it to the method's signature, and use it like this:

```
class UserSession
  def add_comment(session, comment)
    session[:comment_ids] ||= []
    session[:comment_ids] << comment.id
  end
end
```

And in your controller:

```
if @comment.save
    user_session.add_comment(session, @comment)

    flash[:notice] = "Comment Successfully created"
    redirect_to @post
else
    redirect_to :back
end
```